# Wrong query result in sqlalchemy ZopeTransactionExtension

Tags: python, mysql, transactions, sqlalchemy, bottle

I have application on bottle.py. This application work with MySQL through sqlalchemy. Start version I am simple define session and do commit.

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = Session()

class Message(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'messages'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  type = Column(String(30), index=True)
  text = Column(Text, default='')

  def add_message(self, data_message):
    new_message = Message(
        type=data_message.get('type'),
        text=data_message.get('text'),
        status=1
    )

    session.add(new_message)
    session.commit()

    return new_message

  def get_messages(self)
    messages = session.query(Message)\
                      .filter_by(type='sms', status=1)\
                      .order_by(Message.create_datetime)\
                      .all()[0:int(offset)]
    return messages
```

All work good. But in cause mysql connection error, connection broken and repeat rollback error.
I change my code with zope.transaction.

```
engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine, extension=ZopeTransactionExtension(), expire_on_commit=False))

class Message(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'messages'
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  type = Column(String(30), index=True)
  text = Column(Text, default='')

  def add_message(self, data_message):
    new_message = Message(
        type=data_message.get('type'),
        text=data_message.get('text'),
        status=1
    )

    session = Session()
    with transaction.manager:
      session.add(new_message)
      transaction.commit()

    return new_message

  def get_messages(self)
    session = Session()
    messages = session.query(Message)\
                      .filter_by(type='sms', status=1)\
                      .order_by(Message.create_datetime)\
                      .all()[0:int(offset)]
    return messages
```

In this case error with rollback away. But, in query get messages work like with 'cache'. For first query all result correct, but continue I change field 'status' in MySQL manually and don't get my messages. Only empty list.
I am try ZopeTransactionExtension('changed'), mark_changed(session) after define 'session' in function.

Write me for questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me it wrapper query in 'with tansaction.manager':

```
with transaction.manager:
  messages = session.query(Message)\
                  .filter_by(type='sms', status=1)\
                  .order_by(Message.create_datetime)\
                  .all()[0:int(offset)]
```